# Error when compiling report after packaged into JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, compiler-errors, jasper-reports

so I have developed this program in Java using Eclipse (jdk 1.8.0_74) on Windows 7 which the user can at some point generate a report with data coming from database.

To create this report I have used TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.3.0 which generates these .jrxml and .jasper. In order to my program recognize these files, I copied them into a report package.

When I run on Eclipse, everything works absolutely fine; the report is generated, able to print, everything.

Now the problem: When I export into runnable JAR (**Export > Runnable JAR File > Extract required libraries into generated JAR**) it doesn't generate at all; shows me a compile error.

There goes the following code:

```
public final void gerarRelatorio() {
    if (dateChooser.getDate() == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Preencha o campo de data!");
    } else {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seu relatório será gerado...");

            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("RelatorioAttr.jrxml"));

            if (new DAORelatorioImpl().preencherRelatorioATratar(dateChooser.getCalendar())
                    .isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Nenhum dado foi encontrado para essa data!");
            } else {
                JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null,
                        new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(new DAORelatorioImpl()
                                .preencherRelatorioATratar(dateChooser.getCalendar())));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Relatório Gerado com Sucesso!");

                JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(print, false);
                jv.setVisible(true);
                jv.toFront();
            }

        } catch (HeadlessException | JRException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Erro 1: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConexaoException | DAOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Erro 2: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Again when running on Eclipse it works just fine, but this exception happens when I try to use on compiled JAR:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report java source files: C:\Users\guilherme.brandao\workspace\RelatorioAttr_1472481426930_73428.java
```

I have no clue how to solve this mostly because I don't even know what this file is or where it is created.

I would be grateful for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Note that unless you have Java code that modifies the report at runtime, compiling the `.jrxml` file into a `.jasper` file is not necessary. You can load and fill the `.jasper` file produced by iReport or JasperSoft Reports directly. This will reduce the time it takes to generate a report, and simplify the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by changing to load the .jasper which is already compiled instead of the .jrxml by the following code:

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager
            .compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("RelatorioAttr.jrxml"));
```

to

```
InputStream jasperStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("RelatorioAttr.jasper");
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
```